# How to reset the appearance of reusable cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

In my view controller I register my custom cell like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load the NIB file
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"FTRecordCellView" bundle:nil];

    // Register this NIB which contains the cell
    [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FTRecordCellView"];
}
```

In the cell creation method I reuse the cell like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FTRecordCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FTRecordCellView"];

    //change colour of one cell
    if(...) {
      [[cell cellBackgroundView] setBackgroundColor:currentDayColor];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that the cell with the changed background colour is reused when going further down (offscreen) and the background colour of that reused cell is not set to original. But I intend to change the background color of only one cell.  How can I address this problem?

Comment: reset the background color in the else statements. [    if(...) {
      [[cell cellBackgroundView] setBackgroundColor:currentDayColor];
    } else {//reset}]

Comment: As Danyun states, due to cell reuse you must always set a cell's attributes for both sets of conditions. Never have an `if` without an `else` when setting up a cell.

Answer (score 4):

This is what `prepareForReuse` is for. Set things back to their default state in this method. Alternatively, use a different reuse identifier for the one cell, or set the background colour in either case in your `cellForRow...` method.

Comment: Yes the second proposal is a solution as Danyun mentioned. The first one; is `prepareForReuse` a method? Can't find it.

Comment: Yes, it's a method on UITableViewCell